# Centering banner image on screen resize

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where a banner image (the "Review Us" text and lines) is not centering correctly when trying to adjust the screen size. Here is a before and after of what my issue is. The after image is also showing the same results on mobile screens
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JQUl.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITbiV.png)

The HTML for that image goes as followed:

```
<div class="rowBanner">
     <img src="images/reviewus.png" alth="review">
</div>
```

The only CSS in effect is on

```
div.rowBanner{
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I would like the "Review Us" text part of the image to be centered (left-to-right) regardless of screen width

Comment: We don't have nearly enough code here to be able to diagnose this issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: show all your banner HTML. I'm sure your banner logo is in the wrong place ~.~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have might be from desktop to mobile the hambuger menu shift your logo. using position absolute with `transform: translate(-50%, 0%);` will center your img by its own width.

```
.rowBanner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

> Centering Percentage Width/Height Elements
>
> REF: https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
}

.rowBanner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="rowBanner">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alth="review">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css to the image:

```
div.rowBanner > img {
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

> Edited: Added a maximum with to the img, 100vw means 100 viewport width units, See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: no luck. It's fine when the image exceeds the screen size is where it fails to center.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following CSS:

```
div.rowBanner {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:80%;
}
```

Comment: no luck. It's fine when the image exceeds the screen size is where it fails to center.

Answer (score 0):

What about using CCS **background-image** to set your image. You can then control where the center point is on different resolutions via **background-position**

```js
function resize(isDesktop) {
  if (isDesktop) {
    $('.banner').css('width', '100%');
  } else {
    $('.banner').css('width', '200px');
  }
}
```

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qh7LLydY8eo/maxresdefault.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 175px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="resize(true)">Desktop</button>
<button onclick="resize()">Mobile</button>

<div class="page">
  <div class="banner">
  </div>
</div>
```